# Django SelectDateWidget not rendering correctly

Tags: python, django, html, django-forms, django-widget

I am trying to render the built-in SelectDateWidget in Django, however in the webpage it shows as

`<django.forms.widgets.SelectDateWidget object at 0xb4f6bc6c> Submit`

I am new to Django, I read the documentation and looked up on the internet, but couldn't came up with a solution.

Here is my,

**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.forms.widgets import SelectDateWidget

def yillik(request):
    form = SelectDateWidget()
    return render(request, 'izinyillik.html', {'form': form})
```

**izinyillik.html**

```
<form method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
     {{ form }}
     <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Where is your *actual* form? You cannot use a widget as a form.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use a widget on its own like that. A widget needs to live in a field, which in turn needs to live on a form. You need to declare them both:

```
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    my_field = forms.DateField(widget=SelectDateWidget)
```

Answer (score 0):

Problem is you are rendering *widget* you should use form

Create a form

**forms.py**:

```
from django import forms
class MyForm(forms.Form):
    date= forms.DateField(widget=forms.extras.widgets.SelectDateWidget)
```

In **views.py**:

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from forms import MyForm
def yillik(request):
    form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'izinyillik.html', {'form': form})
```